# Connecting homomorphism in Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading the proof of theorem 2.16 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (page 117). In the part where he proves $\operatorname{Im} j_* \subset \ker i_*$, he writes the following:

> "A homology class in $\ker(j_*)$ is represented by a cycle $b \in B_n$ with $j(b)$ a boundary, so $j(b) = \partial c'$ for some $c' \in C_{n+1}$".

I don't understand why $j(b)$ is a boundary. For this, we'd have to show that $j(b) \in \operatorname{im}(\partial_{n+1})$. However, I was only able to show that $j_n(b) = j_n(\tilde{b}) + \partial_{n+1}(j_{n+1}(b'))$ for $b=\tilde{b} + \partial_{n+1}(b')$, where $\tilde{b} \in \ker(\partial_n)$ and $b' \in B_{n+1}$. So $j_n(b)$ is almost an element of $\operatorname{Im}(\partial_{n+1})$, only the element $j_n(\tilde{b})$ is in the way.

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$j(b)$ represents $j_*([b])$ in the codomain of $j_*.$ Since $[b] \in \operatorname{ker}(j_*),$ this $j(b)$ has to represent zero homology class. This means precisely that it is someone's boundary.